# Paypal Live Subscription : Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3, and T3 parameters for a subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I made a subscription button in sandbox which is working perfectly. But when I make a button in live, it throws the below error

```
Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3, and T3 parameters for a subscription.
```

**My Sandbox Code:**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FPHQZ37TC27R2">
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="VaccineXpress Subscription">VaccineXpress Subscription</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="1 Provider : $59.00 USD - monthly">1 Provider : $59.00 USD - monthly : $59.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="1 Additional Provider : $68.00 USD - monthly">1 Additional Provider : $68.00 USD - monthly : $68.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="2 Additional Providers : $77.00 USD - monthly">2 Additional Providers : $77.00 USD - monthly : $77.00 USD - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

**My Live code:**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FD2ZRKMF3EPDC">
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>

<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="VaccineXpress Subscription">VaccineXpress Subscription</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="1 Provider : $59.00 USD â monthly">1 Provider : $59.00 USD â monthly : $1.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="1 Additional Provider : $68.00 USD â monthly">1 Additional Provider : $68.00 USD â monthly : $68.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="2 Additional Providers : $77.00 USD â monthly">2 Additional Providers : $77.00 USD â monthly : $77.00 USD - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I made the button from create button section. I set the return url from selling tools as well. Please tell where I am making mistake in live. There is not any a3, p3 & t3 in sandbox or live code.

Do I have to do any Payment / Account setup for the same.
Do I have to do "Link your bank account" from Account Setup.

Pleas guide on the same.

Answer (score 1):

These three variables define the terms of your subscription. What you have built is basically a Buy now button, because there is no mechanism to collect future payments.

`<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
 <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">`

This translates to $0.01 billed every month. In a hosted, or saved button, these variables are not visible in the source code.

Also, subscription buttons don't support drop down menus. In your use case you would need to create a separate button for each of the options in the drop down.